# How could I convert a simple XML to CSV using Python?

Tags: python, xml, csv

This is my XML file `test.xml`:

```
<nodes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/nodes_file.xsd">
    <node id="0" x="0.0" y="0.0" type="traffic_light"/> 
    <node id="1" x="0.0" y="500.0" type="priority"/> 
    <node id="2" x="500.0" y="0.0" type="priority"/> 
    <node id="3" x="0.0" y="-500.0" type="priority"/>
    <node id="4" x="-500.0" y="0.0" type="priority"/>

</nodes>
```

I want to convert it to a CSV file which contains the following columns:
`id, x, y, type`. So it would be something like this:

```
id,x,y,type
0,0.0,0.0,traffic_light
1,0.0,500.0,priority
2,500.0,0.0,priority
3,0.0,-500.0,priority
4,-500.0,0.0,priority
```

How could I do it via Python? Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) and [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) modules:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import csv

tree = et.parse('node.xml')
nodes = tree.getroot()
with open('node.csv', 'w') as ff:
    cols = ['id','x','y','type']
    nodewriter = csv.writer(ff)
    nodewriter.writerow(cols)
    for node in nodes:
        values = [ node.attrib[kk] for kk in cols]
        nodewriter.writerow(values)
```

Comment: where does [kk] come from?

Comment: @y.y see [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)